# Truncate tables in kettle job is not working

Tags: pentaho, kettle

When we are using "truncate table" step which is in Utility, its not work.
We have created one job, after start step we use this step.
when we run this job its not work also does not show the errors.

Comment: Can you truncate the tables directly by issuing the appropriate SQL? Also, what's your DB? Are you sure you have the connection set up properly, and are you sure you have needed rights?

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of your PDI and please check the data base connection and table name.